# SQL Statement stored in separate folder

Tags: php, mysql, security

Was just wondering from a security standpoint, is it good to have my SQL statements stored in a separate folder like my "files" folder and call them when I need them? Or is this too cumbersome?

I was thinking maybe storing all the statements in one file but I would appreciate input on this.

An example of what I mean.

```
require('files\selectriskrating.php');
```

And in the files folder I have a selectdetails.php with

```
$query="SELECT `Riskrating` FROM `currentdetails` WHERE 1";
```

Comment: Place them outside the `public_html` domain.

Comment: Why not store them within the db? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines.html

Comment: Hmm yes I could try this, what is your opinion on what I am doing at the moment?

Comment: Are you asking Alex K. or myself? @Strobes - When responding to a person in particular, do use the `@` symbol followed by the person's name, that way the person in question will receive notification. We can't keep checking this thread to see "who said what to who" ;-)

Comment: @AlexK - What is your opinion on what I am doing at the moment?

Comment: I would use an abstraction layer (see Symfony or Laravel). At the least I would wrap the SQL in functions so that I could quickly and easily fetch the data without having to hassle with file includes and/or MySQL boilerplate.

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is your concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly safe*.  You don't need to keep it outside of your web root as another commenter noted because it the server will evaluate it as php and never echo it to the browser.

However, it is a very cumbersome way of managing your SQL.  You are relying on your include to always be error free, in that it always assigns the (presumably) global variable of $query with the right SQL statement.  You are also adding a very confusing layer around the SQL itself that will make it hard for others to try to read your code (or even yourself in the future).

An improvement would be to save the statements as text files.  If what you are trying to get at is separation of concerns, then save just the statements as text files, such that

```
SELECT `Riskrating` FROM `currentdetails` WHERE 1;
```

is located in files/myquery.sql. Then load it with

```
$query = file_get_contents('files/myquery.sql');
```

This way, you are eliminating one potential source of errors and you can automatically loop over all of your queries and check them for correctness (eg, in a unit test).  Note that if you do this, you will have to keep your queries outside of the document root because they can be shown in the browser.

However, a much better approach is to use an ORM such as [RedBean](http://www.redbeanphp.com/) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).  This way, you don't have to mess around with your database layer at all.

* Assuming that the file contents are actually:

```
&lt;?php $query = "sql statement";
```

Comment: Separate text files for each query? Glad I don't have to maintain code like that!

Comment: @Dave I would never do that either, but that is already what he is doing... only embedding code in them.  That is why I called it cumbersome.

Comment: @Matt Thank you very much for the in depth answer.   I appreciate it.  I will take into consideration what you said about an ORM.  I wasn't necessarily going to use includes just wanted to see what opinions people had and if there was an alternative :)